# Servlet JSP connection problem in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat7, servlets

I have tomcat 7.0.14, jdk1.6 and Eclipse Indigo for Java EE web app developers.
I am new to JSP, so tried Eclipse as I thought it made coding easier. I closely followed [this video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUkzMsbZetA).

I created 2 files under my project prison- login.java, home.html and modified web.xml too.
When I click the submit button in the login(this is 1st page) page, it shows only this error:

```
   File not found
          Firefox can't find the file at /D:/eclipse/Workspace/Prisonhome/WebContent/WEB-INF/Log?user=sa&pass=sa&action=That's+me.
```

I dont know if it isn't sufficient to save project in workspace.

There were several discrepancies between file locations given in video and my Eclipse files. Eg.: `web.xml` in my Eclipse was located in servers->apache-tomcat directory, instead of  web content->WEB_INF->lib->web.xml. is it important?

my code:
index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Welcome :) </title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="Log" method="get">
            <B>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Username: <input type=text name="user"><br><br>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Password: <input type=text name="pass"><br><br>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=submit name=action value="That's me" style="background-color:666666; color:ffffff; border-color:ee0088">
            </B></font>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Login.java:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String uname=request.getParameter("user");
    String passwd=request.getParameter("pass");
    response.getWriter().println("<html><head>This is the response!</head>");
    response.getWriter().println("<body>Response!!</body></html>");
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Log</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.prisonhome.packs.Login</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Log</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Log/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: note that if an answer has worked for you, you should mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Firefox can't find the file at /D:/eclipse/Workspace/Prisonhome/WebContent/WEB-INF/Log?user=sa&pass=sa&action=That's+me.

You need to open the page by a real web URL, not by a local disk file system path. If Tomcat is running at localhost on port 8080 and the webapp context name is `Prisonhome` then you need to invoke it by

> http://localhost:8080/Prisonhome/index.html

As to the tutorials, I'd recommend to read the [Coreservlets.com](http://coreservlets.com) tutorials. You can find a list of links at bottom of our [Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, using GET to login is not really safe as everyone can see the password in the URL. The HTML `<font>` tag is deprecated since 1998, use CSS instead. Using a plethora of `<br>` and `&nbsp;` tags is also unnecessary, use CSS positions/margins/paddings instead.

Comment: thank you very much sir! but it seems my tomcat is not starting up properly. i will follow your advice as soon as i setup the tomcat correctly. suppose i reinstall tomcat, where would i need to make changes to overwrite previous tomcat pointers?

Comment: Nothing, basically. That is, when you installed it by just downloading and extracting the zip. Just deleting the extracted folder ought to be enough. You only need to ensure that you shutdown it first.

Comment: Now my tomcat works correctly. I tested it with a simple project with html and jsp files. when i run each file, i get the correct output in the working space. but when i reconfigured the server to include my project and clicked run main.html, it only shows 'The requested resource (/Prisonhome/main.jsp) is not available.'  HTTP Status 404. What could be missing?

Comment: i have Prisonhome in the same directory as the other simple hello project. i've also copied the web.xml file to WEB_INF and WEB_INF/lib

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the file on tomcat - i.e. `http://localhost:8080/Prisonhome/index.html`. Don't launch it from the file explorer.

To make that work, you need to have the application deployed, and the server (tomcat) running.